# Javascript - Validando campo numérico (popup)

Tags: javascript, html5

Eu tenho uma tela que tem 4 inputs. O valor desses inputs está sendo salvo no meu banco de dados. Mas preciso descobrir como eu faço para poder validar esses campos sendo campos apenas numéricos?

Tentei um code achado na web, mas não deu muito certo.

```
function checkNumber(valor) {
        var regra = /^[0-9]+$/;
        if (valor.match(regra)) {
            alert("Numero: "+valor);
        }else{
            alert("Permitido somente números);
        }
    };


 <button class="botao1" onblur="checkNumber(this.value);" onclick="publish(JSON.stringify(pl),topic, 2);">3. Publish</button>
```

Comment: O evento onblur é para quando vc tirar o foco do campo e vc está colocando ele no botão, você também está passando o value do botão e não dos inputs.

Uma forma de funcionar é você colocar a função checkNumber(this.value) no evento onblur de cada input.

Comment: Tipo assim Diego? 

<label class="label">Humidity: </label>
            <input type="text" id="humidity" size="50" value="" onblur="checkNumber(this.value);">
            <br>

Comment: Além do que o @DiegoSchmidt disse, acho que você poderia criar uma variavél  regexp `var regra =new RegExp("/^[0-9]+$/")` e na hora de validar o regexp use `regra.test(valor)`

Comment: Correto, assim mesmo. Antes você estava passando o valor do botão e do seu input.

Comment: Mas se está usando html5 porque não utilize o input type="number"?

Comment: @LeonardoBonetti: Não entendi muito bem..

Comment: @Everson: eu não faço ideia.. Como eu disse, conheço muito pouco de linguagem web, por isso vim até vcs mesmo..

Comment: @cardealt Descrevi na minha resposta como é a sintaxe do input do tipo number (número ) e uma solução com javascript para restringir o campo somente a números.

Answer (score 1):

O evento onblur é para quando vc tirar o foco do campo e vc está colocando ele no botão, 
você também está passando o value do botão e não dos inputs.

Uma forma de funcionar é você colocar a função checkNumber(this.value) no evento onblur de cada input.

Um exemplo funcionando da maneira da sua pergunta:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Título da pagina</title>
        <script>
            function checkNumber(value) {
                if (value.trim() !== "") {
                    var regra = /^[0-9]+$/;
                    if (value.match(regra)) {
                        alert("Numero: " + value);
                    } 
                    else {
                        alert("Permitido somente números");
                    }
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <input type="text" name="idade" id="idade" onblur="checkNumber(this.value)"/>
    </body>
</html>
```

Um exemplo validando varios campos onde contenham uma determinada classe:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Título da pagina</title>      
        <script>
            function validaCamposSomenteNumero() {
                var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName("somente-numero");
                for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; ++i) {
                    var input = inputs[i];  
                    if (input.value !== "") {
                        if (isNaN(input.value)) {
                            alert("Preencha somente número!");
                            return;
                        }
                    }               
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <input type="text" name="idade" id="idade" class="somente-numero"/>
        <input type="text" name="idade2" id="idade2" class="somente-numero"/>
        <input type="button" value="Cadastrar" onclick="validaCamposSomenteNumero()"/>
    </body>
</html>
```

Um exemplo onde vc queira que um campo tenha exatamente 4 números, a idade por exemplo, usando HTML5.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Título da pagina</title>      
    </head>

    <body>
        <form action="" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="idade" id="idade" pattern="^[0-9]{4}$" title="Preencha a idade corretamente."/>
            <input type="submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Permitindo que um campo contenha somente números usando HTML5:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Título da pagina</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <input type="number" name="idade" id="idade"/>
    </body>
</html>
```

Respondendo sua pergunta de como habilitar outro campo caso determinado campo seja válido, usei a propridade disabled do html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Título da pagina</title>  
        <script>
            function validaCampo(value) {
                if (value.trim() !== "") {
                    var campoParaHabilitar = document.getElementById("campo2");
                    if (!isNaN(value.trim())) {
                        campoParaHabilitar.disabled = false;
                    }
                    else {
                        campoParaHabilitar.disabled = true;
                    }

                }       
            }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <input type="text" name="campo1" id="campo1" onblur="validaCampo(this.value)"/>
        <input type="text" name="campo2" id="campo2" disabled/>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Perfeito Diego!! Muito obrigada!!! :)

Comment: Resolveu, mas posso fazer uma pergunta? 

E se eu quisesse que enquanto o input estiver preenchido com caracter diferente de número, não permitir pular para o input seguinte, como faria?

Comment: Editei a resposta.

Comment: Muito obrigada!!

Answer (score 0):

Você pode restringir para que o usuário não digite nenhum outro caractere a não ser números através de uma máscara para cada campo. Com a máscara você consegue definir quantos dígitos numéricos cada campo deverá ter. 
No exemplo abaixo os campos estão restritos a 4, 5, 6 e 7 dígitos, respectivamente.

```js
jQuery(function($){
   $("#numero1").mask("9999");
   
   $("#numero2").mask("99999");
   
   $("#numero3").mask("999999");
   
   $("#numero4").mask("9999999");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.14.0/jquery.mask.js"></script>

Número 1 <input type="text" id="numero1" name="numero" maxlength="4" placeholder="4 dígitos numéricos"/><br><br>
Número 2 <input type="text" id="numero2" name="numero" maxlength="5" placeholder="5 dígitos numéricos"/><br><br>
Número 3 <input type="text" id="numero3" name="numero" maxlength="6" placeholder="6 dígitos numéricos"/><br><br>
Número 4 <input type="text" id="numero4" name="numero" maxlength="7" placeholder="7 dígitos numéricos"/><br><br>
```

Ou, se preferir utilizar somente o HTML5, utilize o campo do tipo `number`.

```
Número <input type="number" name="numero">
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript tem funções nativas bem simples que podem lhe ajudar nesse caso. Experimente no console:

```
var foo;
// preencha foo
isNaN(Number(foo)); //retornará verdadeiro se foo não for uma representação de um número
```

Como funciona: a função `Number` tenta converter o valor para numérico, e somente em caso de falha retorna [`NaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN) (valor fixo para significar "número inválido"). A segunda função verifica se o valor informado a ela é um `NaN`.

Vantagens de se usar a função [`isNaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) em conjunto com a [`Number`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number):

- Muito rápidas, pois são implementadas no navegador;
- Menos código para manter;
- O código que você encontrou na internet não considera números não-inteiros (e.g.: 2.1) como números. A combinação acima considera;
- Usar funções básicas do Javascript é uma forma agnóstica a frameworks de se resolver problemas. E você pode validar valores que não necessariamente vieram do formulário, se um dia tiver que validar dados de outras fontes.

Você só precisa de uma função mais rebuscada se você quiser forçar um **formato** de número, mas aí é outro problema.

Comment: Acho que não entendi muito bem :/

Answer (score 0):

Validação somente números com um ponto separando casas decimais.   [**DEMO**](http://kithomepage.com/sos/somente-numeros.htm)

**SCRIPT**

```
function checkfloat(e,field){
  if (!(((e.keyCode>=48)&&(e.keyCode<=57))||(e.keyCode==46)))
  {
     alert("Somente numeros inteiros ou fracionários separado por ponto!");
     e.keyCode=0;                   
  }

  if (e.keyCode==46)
  {
     var patt1=new RegExp("\\.");        
     var ch =patt1.exec(field); 

     if(ch==".")
     {
         alert("Mais que um ponto decimal não é permitido");
         e.keyCode=0;
     }                     
  }      
}
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="a" size="5" onkeypress="checkfloat(event, this.value)">
<input type="text" id="b" size="5" onkeypress="checkfloat(event, this.value)">
<input type="text" id="c" size="5" onkeypress="checkfloat(event, this.value)">
<input type="text" id="d" size="5" onkeypress="checkfloat(event, this.value)">
```

Comment: Muito obrigada pelo retorno :))